# How to make first and last letters capital in a word (therefore multiple strings) php

Tags: php, string, uppercase

What I am currently trying to accomplish is to make the first and last letters of a word(s) uppercase.

Currently this is my function:

```
function ManipulateStr($input){
    return strrev(ucwords(strrev($input)));
}
```

However this only changes the last letter of every word to uppercase, now I'm trying to wrap my mind around how to also get the first letter of every word capitalized.

An example:

> input: hello my friends
>
> output: HellO MY FriendS

Perhaps I will have to use a substr? But how would that work seeing as I want this to be applicable to either multiple words or a single word?

Comment: `return ucwords(strrev(ucwords(strrev($input))));`

Comment: your desired output please..

Comment: @FrayneKonok - It's right there in the question `output: HellO MY FriendS
`

Comment: thank you so much! I had a feeling I was missing something small!

Comment: What should `input: hello, my friEnds` produce?

Comment: Looks like a job interview question? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first time make your string all lower case by using `strtolower` and then use the function `ucwords` to capitalize the first character then use `strrev` again and apply `ucwords` for capitalize other first characters. 
then finally use the `strrev` for get back the original string with first and last character capitalized.

**Updated Function**

```
function ManipulateStr($input){
    return strrev(ucwords(strrev(ucwords(strtolower($input)))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a surprisingly faster function (~20% faster) than [Frayne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480928/2191572) provided then try this:

```
function ManipulateStr($input)
{
    return implode(
        ' ', // Re-join string with spaces
        array_map(
            function($v)
            {
                // UC the first and last chars and concat onto middle of string
                return strtoupper(substr($v, 0, 1)).
                       substr($v, 1, (strlen($v) - 2)).
                       strtoupper(substr($v, -1, 1));
            },
            // Split the input in spaces
            // Map to anonymous function for UC'ing each word
            explode(' ', $input)
        )
    );

    // If you want the middle part to be lower-case then use this
    return implode(
        ' ', // Re-join string with spaces
        array_map(
            function($v)
            {
                // UC the first and last chars and concat onto LC'ed middle of string
                return strtoupper(substr($v, 0, 1)).
                       strtolower(substr($v, 1, (strlen($v) - 2))).
                       strtoupper(substr($v, -1, 1));
            },
            // Split the input in spaces
            // Map to anonymous function for UC'ing each word
            explode(' ', $input)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I fear this will give incorrect results on strings with punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a regex pattern with an alternation where a word boundary is either before or after an encountered word character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tQUqY))

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b\w|\w\b/', fn($m) => strtoupper($m[0]), $string);
```

Alternatively, a conditional regex pattern can match an optional leading word boundary, then a word character, then if there was no word boundary before the word character enforce that the word character is immediately followed by a word boundary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/meHKJ))

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\b)?\w(?(1)|\b)/', fn($m) => strtoupper($m[0]), $string);
```

When either of the above snippets are fed:

```
$string = 'i must say hello to my handsome friends';
```

The output is:

```
I MusT SaY HellO TO MY HandsomE FriendS
```